# Can I take the plates off a car for my handicapped mother in law whose name is on the registration and insurance without getting in trouble?

Tags: licensing, license-plates

Suppose that an older woman, Abby  shares a car with her younger relative Ben.  Suppose further that the title has both their names on it.

Suppose that the registration and insurance are in her name alone. Suppose that Ben has possession of the car and is not sharing it as was agreed.  Suppose that Abby has had enough and wants to cancel the registration and insurance. She is handicapped and asked another relative, Chris (Ben is Chris's brother-in-law and Abby is Chris's mother-in-law) to go to Ben's apartment complex and remove the plates for her so they can be turned in. With Abby's permission, does the law permit Chris to remove the plates and turn them in on Abby's behalf?

Comment: Laws on such things vary significantly by jurisdiction. For a useful answer, please specify the jurisdiction, that is the country, and if in a Federal country such as Canada, India, or the US, the province or state. Otherwise it may be answered for any jurisdiction that anyone chooses to answer for. Andorra, perhaps.

Comment: Does Chris have a proper **power of attorney** to act in this specific case for Abby?

Comment: Does the title say "Abby **and** Ben", or "Abby **or** Ben?

Comment: "Suppose further that the title has both their names on it. Suppose that the registration and insurance are in her name alone." Not sure that this is generally possible. Registration is issued based upon title, and as a matter of commercial practice and regulatory requirements, insurance is never in the name of just one owner of a vehicle with more than one owner. Usually you have to show insurance of everyone on title (or swear that you have it) to get the registration and plates. A name on title isn't effective until submitted to the DMV.

Comment: In many U.S. jurisdictions this scenario cannot occur at all since cars have to be registered to their exact owner(s). In some U.S. jurisdictions there are laws requiring that doctors prescribe disability plates, and punishing misuse by third parties, which would also prevent plating such a plate on someone else's car. If you specify your jurisdiction we can provide an answer.